# Safari css mask rendering issue

Tags: css, safari, rendering, mask

I would like to use a css mask for a header to create a curved cut for an image.

For this I want to use the css technique mask-image. Since I only want the curved line at the bottom, I'm using two elements to create the mask. A white linear gradient as a filler and an SVG with the curved line to cut out. The image of the plants was set as an background-image.

```
.masked-section
{

    background-image: url(../background.jpg);

    -webkit-mask-image: url(../HeaderMask.svg), linear-gradient(white, white);
    mask-image: url(../HeaderMask.svg), linear-gradient(white, white);
    -webkit-mask-composite: xor;
    mask-composite: exclude;
    -webkit-mask-position: bottom, top;
    mask-position: bottom, top;
    -webkit-mask-size: contain, cover;
    mask-size: contain, cover;
    -webkit-mask-repeat: no-repeat;
    mask-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Everything works fine in Chrome and Firefox. Only in Safari there are problems with rendering at the bottom edge. A flash through the background image of around 1px height. The problem only occurs at some screen widths, so I resized the window to show the effect better.

[image]

I can only assume that there is a problem in the subpixel area when rendering.

```css
body
{
  background-color: #fefefe;
}

#header
{
  background-image: url('https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/01/31/07/36/secret-3120483_1280.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  
  aspect-ratio: 3 / 1;
  
   -webkit-mask-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,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'), linear-gradient(white, white);
    mask-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,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'), linear-gradient(white, white);
    -webkit-mask-composite: xor;
    mask-composite: exclude;
    -webkit-mask-position: bottom, top;
    mask-position: bottom, top;
    -webkit-mask-size: contain, cover;
    mask-size: contain, cover;
    -webkit-mask-repeat: no-repeat;
    mask-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#content1
{
  padding: 3rem;
}
```

```html
<section id="header">
</section>
<section id="content1">
Lorem Ipsum
</section>
```

Comment: *the relatively new* --> not really new by the way. It's been there since a lot of years

Comment: Well, realtive is relatively different for everyone. ;-)
But I have changed the sentence if that should really bother you

Comment: Does setting the background image to no-repeat remove the problem?

Comment: The css class in my question is only a part of it. The background image is already set to no-repeat. And one more thing that you cannot see clearly in this animated gif, the position of the curved mask is not always positioned correctly wile resizing. It seems to snap on unregular points. This does not occur in the other brothers.

Comment: Can you give more complete code, for example I can’t see where the background is set to no repeat, preferably create a runnable snippet so we can experience the problem, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I added the snippet, and in Safari you can clearly see the position error on the left side, which adjusts unevenly depending on the size change. (Use the full page function). But in this example i can see the issue in chrome browser too.